# C# SqlDataReader only returns values > 0

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

This has been bugging me for the past several hours and I can't seem to find the answer..

I have the following query

```
SELECT        A, SUM(B) AS total
FROM          table
GROUP BY      A
```

now the column B in table can only hold 0 or 1.
and A is total1, total2 or total3

now when I use this directly in the SQL database I get a nice table holding

```
A        total
total1   1
total2   0
toatl3   5
```

This is exactly what I want it to do.
However if using in my c# program. if one of the totals is 0 it is not displayed at all..
Below is the code I'm using but it only works fine when total1, total2 and total3 are bigger then 0
so the table above would only display total1 and total3...

```
string total = "A        total";       
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here I know");
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand total = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT A, SUM(B) AS total FROM table GROUP BY A", conn);

    SqlDataReader total_reader = total.ExecuteReader();
    while (total_reader.Read())
    {
        total += total_reader["A"].ToString() + "  " + total_reader["total"] + "\n";
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    serverstats += err.ToString();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

How can I make it so that it would display the table properly, even if total1, total2 and total3 are 0

thus displaying:

```
A        total
total1   0
total2   0
toatl3   0
```

I know that a 0 in SQL generally equals to null and such.

I suspect that this is the reason that C# assumes that if the value is 0 that it is not of interest.

I hope I explained it properly enough, thanks for any help in advance!

=======EDIT======

COALESCE or ISNULL does not make a difference :(

I assume it's to do with the C# reader bit not in the SQL querying bit.

As you can see in my example the SQL bit DOES create a table with the correct Rows and does not write them as NULL. But the C# bit seems to read it as NULL.

Comment: I doubt this will fix the problem but have you tried calling ToString() on total_reader["total"]?

Comment: @SquidScareMe `ToString()` is already being called automatically.

Comment: What datatype is B?  Is it a bit field?

Comment: Please Don't catch System.Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  column B can have nulls, try

```
SELECT        A, COALESCE(SUM(B),0) AS total
FROM          table
GROUP BY      A
```

Comment: Shouldn't you sum(coalesce(b,0))?

Comment: THanks, but I did try that already. as well as the ISNULL..
My guess is the C# SqlDataReader bit is to blame for reading the 0 as a NULL road

Answer (score 1):

which sql database are you using? sql server or mysql?

or try to edit the line:

`total += total_reader["A"].ToString() + "  " + total_reader["total"] + "\n";`

to

`total += total_reader["A"].ToString() + "  " + int.Parse(total_reader["total"].ToString()) + "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out that I had WHERE (B = 1)

I forgot to take this out of my SQL query..

Thanks for the help :)